# How to ensure '#' gets escaped in an html label?

Tags: javascript, html, escaping

I have used this library to decode, which worked great: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he

But, encoding did not work. I grab components manually, and users get to choose the name. I cam across the situation where a component was named '# to call', which breaks my template because of the '#', and he.encode() from the library above does not encode the '#'. I tried encodeURIComponent(), which changes it to %23%20to%20call, but when the html template is brought up, it is back to '# to call'.

How can I make sure the # is escaped, along with any other potential problem characters?

Comment: `#` is not a character that needs to be escaped/encoded...

Comment: I guess kendo templates do. Sorry, didn't realize it was specific to kendo templates. But I do know it is the # symbol and I'll need to escape it... But I guess I might just have to search through the string for one and escape it. Or a replace might do the job.

Comment: If you're escaping for something in Kendo templates, it seems you should use a couple backslashes.  http://www.telerik.com/forums/escaping-with-new-syntax

Comment: Alright. I was wondering if there was just a good way to ensure everything got encoded/escaped, but didn't realize '#' was specific to kendo and traditional means wouldn't detect '#' as something to be encoded. Replace with '\\' in front along with an encode should do it then